# Color grouped bar chart based on comparison of numbers d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building up a grouped bar chart. In the chart, I want to color one group of bar chart differently because its Missouri number is bigger than the national average number. However, my else if statement doesn't work out for the fill function. Can anyone tell me what should I do to color the chart differently based on the comparison of numbers? Thanks in advance!!

Here is my Code

```
<svg id="bodychart" width="900" height="500" style="display: block; margin: auto"></svg>

<script>

var svg = d3.select("#bodychart"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +")" ); //Not quite understand (??)

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#F63014", "#ABABAB"]);

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

d3.csv("number.csv", function(d, i, columns){
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = + d[columns[i]];
    return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1); 

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.BodyParts; }));
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d3.max(keys, function(key) {return d[key]; }); })]);

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + x0(d.BodyParts) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {return keys.map(function(key){return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.key);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.value);})
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d){return height - y(d.value);})
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {

        if (d.value['Missouri'] > d.value['National_Average']) {
          return z(d.key);
        } else (d.value['Missouri'] < d.value['National_Average']) {
          return "yellow";
        }
        })
      .on("mousemove", function(d){
        tooltip
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
          .style("display", "inline-block")

          .html("<span style='font-weight: bold'>"+ (d.key) +"</span>" + ":" + "<br>" + "$" + d3.format(",.0f")(d.value));

    })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){ tooltip.style("display", "none");});

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, ",.0f"))
      .append("text")
        .attr("x", -32)
        .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
        .attr("dy", "-3em")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text("Dollars");

});
```

Here is my csv file:

```
    BodyParts,Missouri,National_Average
    Arm,115100,169878
    Leg,102697,153221
    Hand,86821,144930
    Thumb,29767,42432
    Index Finger,22325,24474
    Middle Finger,17364,20996
    Ring Finger,17364,14660
    Pinky,10915,11343
    Foot,74418,91779
    Big Toe,19845,23436
    Eye,69457,96700
    Ear,24310,38050
    Testicle,0,27678
```

Comment: You have several problem here: `z` scale has no domain, your `else` shouldn't have a condition and there is no property in `d.value`, besides the fact that `Missouri` and `National Average` are not in the same datum. But forget about all these problems for a while and tell us, what is the rule you want? What should be the color of **each bar** in the pair if M > NA and if M < NA?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you so much for your comment! I didn't even notice the code has so many flaws when I posted this question... Okay, back to your question, I want to set whichever bar has higher number to green and the one has lower number to red. So, if M < NA, M will be red and NA will be green; if M > NA, M will be green while NA will be red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the complete data for each pair lies in the parent selection, you have to get it before doing any comparison.

Thus, when setting the fill for each bar, this...

```
var parentData = d3.select(this.parentNode).data()[0];
```

... will store the data for the pair, that is, `Missouri` and `National_Average`.

Then, use that object to fill the bars conditionally. This is a way to do that (there are shorter ways, of course, but I believe this verbose snippet is more didactic for you):

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    var parentData = d3.select(this.parentNode).data()[0];
    if (d.key === "Missouri") {
        if (parentData.Missouri > parentData.National_Average) {
            return "green"
        } else {
            return "red"
        }
    } else {
        if (parentData.Missouri < parentData.National_Average) {
            return "green"
        } else {
            return "red"
        }
    }
})
```

Here is a plunker showing it: http://plnkr.co/edit/dfjKFUpuiJvLs6wWkO99?p=preview